# Issue converting .json file to Map

Tags: spring-integration

I'm having issues converting a simple JSON message into a Map

Example_1.json:

```
{"toAddress":"aaa@bbb.com",
"fromAddress":"bbb@ccc.com",
"subject":"Subject from JSON",
"body":"Body from JSON"}
```

Spring configuration:

```
<!-- Read file and output to filesIn channel -->
<int:channel id="filesIn" />
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesReader"
                                  directory="file:/C:/data/inputDirectory"
                                  filename-pattern="*.json"
                                  channel="filesIn"
                                  prevent-duplicates="true">
    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="5000" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter> 

<file:file-to-string-transformer input-channel="filesIn" output-channel="strings"/>

<int:json-to-object-transformer input-channel="strings" output-channel="objectsOut" type="java.util.Map"/>

<int:object-to-map-transformer input-channel="objectsOut" output-channel="mapOut"/>

<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter channel="mapOut" directory="file:/C:/data/outputDirectory1" />


<!-- Activate logging -->

<int:channel id="filesIn">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="LoggingChannel" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="strings">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="LoggingChannel" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="objectsOut">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="LoggingChannel" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="mapOut">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="LoggingChannel" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="LoggingChannel" />
<int:service-activator input-channel="LoggingChannel" expression="@LOG.trace('Headers are: {}, Payload is: {} ', headers, payload)" />

<bean id="LOG" class="SafeLoggerFactory" factory-method="getLogger">
    <constructor-arg value="integrationEmailLogger"/>
</bean>
```

Error:

> org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler] - org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: failed to write Message payload to file; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unsupported Message payload type [java.util.HashMap], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={subject=Subject from JSON, fromAddress=bbb@ccc.com, body=Body from JSON, toAddress=aaa@bbb.com}, headers={file_originalFile=C:\data\inputDirectory\Example_1.json, id=be65b982-ef47-0207-2ec9-3fdb04837651, file_name=Example_1.json, timestamp=1575407244281}]

Essentially I would like to convert JSON text into a Map, so that I can use expressions such as payload.toAddress to send emails using an outbound-channel-adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always include the full stack trace; a truncated stack trace is useless.

Why do you have an `object-to-map-transformer`? The `json-to-object-transformer` has already created a map for you; the o-t-m-t is redundant.

The file `int-file:outbound-channel-adapter` doesn't know how to handle a Map payload. That's where the failure is.

Comment: Hi Gary - thanks for the pointers! I removed the file to string and object to map transformers as well as the file outbound channel adapter.

I was then able to enrich the header using info from the payload
`<int-mail:header-enricher input-channel="objectsOut" output-channel="splitMessageChannel">
  <int-mail:to expression="payload.toAddress.toString()"/>
  <int-mail:from expression="payload.fromAddress.toString()"/>
  <int-mail:subject expression="payload.subject.toString()"/>
  <int-mail:content-type value="text/html;"/>
 </int-mail:header-enricher>`